# Extending force:sdls and using lightning :xxx tags in component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, slds

I am on a summer 16 dev box trying to get a hang on lightning apps, I started looking at this documentation. My locker service is disabled

> Enable Lightning LockerService Security   This critical update enables
>   LockerService, a new and advanced security layer for your Lightning
>   Components.   2/11/2017 138 days remaining    **Not Activated**

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/

I am facing issues when trying to extend force:slds to my application

1) How do I extend force:slds in `<aura:application>` to use Lightning design system sytle sheets?

> Failed to save undefined: No APPLICATION named markup://force:slds
>   found :

As per docs :

> Your Lightning Out, LC4VC, and Lightning Application automatically get
>   the Lightning Design System stylesheets and design tokens if they
>   extend force:slds. **This is the easiest way to stay up-to-date and
>   consistent with SLDS enhancements**.

2) When I try to include lightning:XXX tags in my component I get the component not found error. Is this because I have an older version of SLDS package in static resource?

> Failed to save undefined: **No COMPONENT named markup://lightning:badge**
>   found

I am able to add ui:xxx, force:xxx, aura:xxxx tags in the component except the lightning:xxx tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lightning:` components are only available in API 38.0 (Winter '17) and above. They will not be available in your dev org until the production rollout.

Comment: Can you add any sort of reference to back that up?

Comment: is it the same for force:slds too? The lightning docs are very confusing and undocumented compared to classic ones from the past

Comment: Yes, force:slds is part of the winter release. The docs for lightning components are located here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm. Ensure you have selected your current API version in the picker in the upper left hand.

Comment: Awesome, never noticed that salesforce did version control on documentation based on release. Will remember to switch between versions to check the feature availability.

Comment: I'm finding that even after the Winter '17 release, I am unable to extend "force:slds" from an aura:component. I am able to apply it to an aura:application, so it's not an API versioning thing. Is it intended that only top level aura:applications can extend "force:slds"? If so, this is a big limitation no? I mean only aura:components can be rendered in LEx tab, and I want to use SLDS to style my components. So, is my only alternative to create my own SLDS bundle and use ltng:require to pull in static resource (even though the docs using "force:slds").